# Apache 2- Forward all the request from a specific Domain to a different Server in the intranet

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, proxy, mod-proxy

I have two servers:

- A (`192.168.1.100:80`)
- B (`192.168.1.200:8080`)

Both are behind firewall and only port 80 is open and forwarded to server A.

People from outside type `www.mydomain.com` to access my web server A.

Now I would like all of the HTTP from `subdomain.mydomain.com` to go to server B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) to do this.

You set up a host entry on A for subdomain.mydomain.com to point to B, and set up B to serve this domain. You then set up a virtual host on A for subdomain.mydomain.com. This virtual host will reverse proxy / to B.

```
ProxyPass / http://subdomain.mydomain.com/
ProxyPassReverse / http://subdomain.mydomain.com/
```

Comment: Sorry my ignorance. I  added  `subdomain.mydomain.com` to point to `192.168.1.200` hosts file and as I said the web server on B is run on `192.168.1.200:8080`. Also, I added both directives to the `site-availble/default` file. However, it is still not working. I was wondering if someone request externally to `subdomain.mydomain.com` how it would get proxied to the other server.

Comment: the external dns for the subdomain should be set to go to the external address for server A. Server A will then route the requests for the domain by proxying it to the backend.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish that you will need two virtual hosts and mod_proxy enabled.

In sites-enabled, you will want a file containing minimally this (and whatever other config you want):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.mydomain.com

   ... whatever you want to serve
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName subdomain.mydomain.com
   ProxyPass / http://subdomain.mydomain.com/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://subdomain.mydomain.com/
</VirtualHost>
```